# how to get docker container to read from stdin?

Tags: docker

I have a script that I want to use to use Sigil (based on Go's template engine) to populate template files

I'm using a dockerized sigil for this via:

```
docker run -v ${TEMPLATE_DIR}:/tmp/sigil mikegrass/gliderlabs_sigil-docker/sigil -f prometheus-configmap.yaml -p API_SERVER=$api_server_url > $TEMP_FILE
```

This seems a bit clunky with having to map a volume, so I'd rather use STDIN to pass in the file....

So what I'd like is

```
cat ./prometheus-configmap.yaml | docker run mikegrass/gliderlabs_sigil-docker -p API_SERVER=$api_server_url > $TEMP_FILE
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, I get no output.

Googling around I see possible solutions but haven't gotten any to work...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to run the container in interactive mode with `--interactive` or `-i`:

```
cat ./prometheus-configmap.yaml | docker run -i mikegrass/gliderlabs_sigil-docker -p API_SERVER=$api_server_url > $TEMP_FILE
```

Comment: [`docker run` options](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#options)

Answer (score 4):

Without cat:

```
docker run -i mikegrass/gliderlabs_sigil-docker -p API_SERVER=$api_server_url < ./prometheus-configmap.yaml
```