# Reading input files with docker

Tags: c++, docker

I'm writting a C++ program that is run as follows:

```
./program data_file config_file
```

And I want to use docker with it. I've written the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM gcc:7.2.0
ENV MYP /repo
WORKDIR ${MYP}
COPY . ${MYP}

RUN /bin/sh -c 'make'
ENTRYPOINT ["./program"]
CMD ["file1", "file2"]
```

So I `docker build -t test .` it and use `docker run test` and see that everything goes fine with the defaults.

However, if I modify `file1` for instance in my working directory (after build), I note that when I run `docker run test file1 file2`, the `file1` called is the one *inside* the container, and the one entered as argument is being ignored.

Similarly, If I use renamed data and config files, and run `docker run test file3 file4`, I get an error saying that these files does not exist (because they are not in the container).

So, how can I do to make docker recognize these input files passed as arguments, avoiding to use the files that are *contained* in the image?

Docker version is 18.04.0-ce, build 3d479c0af6.

**EDIT**

Another option is to use a `launch.sh` script like:

```
#!/bin/sh
./program "${DATA_FILE}" "${CONFIG_FILE}"
```

So `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` instructions are replaced by the following line in the Dockerfile:

```
CMD ["./launch.sh"]
```

But now if I run:

```
docker run test -e DATA_FILE=file1 -e CONFIG_FILE=file2
```

I get a permission error...

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"-e\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
>   ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing file as argument to Docker container
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41092587/passing-file-as-argument-to-docker-container)

Comment: Its not duplicate if it has not an answer, read it in the flag description

Comment: You might want to use volume to mount file between your host and container. For example, `docker run -v /path/to/file:/program/ test file3 file4`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [volume mechanism](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) for mount a host directory to the container.

Create `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` files in some directory in the host machine. For example we are creating files in the `/var/dir1/` directory. 
Your working dir in the docker container is `/program`.

So when you are running docker you should mount this host directory to container using [-v flag](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)

```
docker run -v /var/dir1/:/program test file1.txt file2.txt
```

Oh, I know why we have problem.

When I am mounting the host directory to working dir I am actually deleting all created files inside container from it working dir including the `./program` binary file. So the `docker run` command is failed. 
therefore we not must mount working directory. We can mount subdirectory of working directory for example.

```
 docker run -v /var/dir1/:/program/dir test dir/file1.txt dir/file2.txt
```

It works for me!

Comment: This also generates an error. When I create a `~/tmp` directory and set there file1 and file2, I run `docker run -v /home/user/tmp/:/program test file1 file2` and get the following:  **docker run -v ~/tmp/:/program test file1 file2 
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"./program\": stat ./program: no such file or directory": unknown.
ERRO[0001] error waiting for container: context canceled**

Comment: @EuGENE What do you get when you run `docker run -v /home/user/tmp/:/program test` ?

Comment: The same error is generated: **docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"./program\": stat ./program: no such file or directory": unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled**

Comment: @EuGENE, I found the problem. I apologize for my inattention in first.

Comment: Nothing to apologize. In fact, I'm in your debt, thank you very much!! Now it works