# How to read from input file inside docker container

Tags: java, docker, containers

I have a simple program in java which is run inside docker container.

I used Eclipse On windows - But I created the linux containers (with windwos docker desktop)

I used Powershell to start container
The image is successfully created

I saw this thread but it didnt help me [c++ program with docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50309605/reading-input-files-with-docker). I have an error using the solution in that answer.

```
PS E:\Java\Test> docker run -v E:\Java\Test:\tt img \tt\in.txt
```

***docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: "\\tt\\in.txt": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.***

***Dockerfile***

```
FROM java:8
COPY  hello.jar app.jar
CMD ["java", "-jar", "app.jar", "pkg.hello"]



public static  void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String fileName ="E:\\Java\\Test\\in.txt";
    List<String> lines = Collections.emptyList();
    lines =   Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    Iterator<String> itr = lines.iterator(); 
    while (itr.hasNext()) 
      System.out.println(itr.next()); 
    }
```

Any ideas, thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Having Docker access External files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30652299/having-docker-access-external-files)

Comment: i tried and I got not found file exception

Comment: Update your question with exactly what you did to try to get the external files to work.

Comment: Also be aware of differences in paths between Linux and Windows.

Comment: I added my solution thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New Docker file

```
FROM java:8

COPY  hello.jar app.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar", "pkg.hello"]
```

Ok after lots of trial and error I found one solution, there might be more than one. I want to explain a bit for those who are not very expert like me,

As we know docker makes a something like a mini OS inside the container, I mean the required libraries and files **+** the application we developed. I tried to run and see  what is inside my directory when running in docker. by running on eclipse on windows it shows the regular path, **E:\Java\....** . **But when I ran it on docker it shows only "/".** and then I tried to see the contents. on windows the files and folders inside the current Dir but **on docker it shows some folders same as LINUX root path folders, bin sbin mnt proc etc.** So I realized that there is a mini linux. *I knew this fact but never seen this result.* So obviously the in.txt is not there in docker file system. ***now we see the docker features like -v.*** it allows us to copy/paste one directory from host, which is windows, to docker container file system. After running this command I saw that a new folder called data is added to docker folders

```
docker run -v ${pwd}:/data img
```

the whole contents of pwd (current directory on Win) is copied to data directory, along with in.txt. now my java program is supposed to be run inside the docker, So i need to change the hard-coded path.

```
String fileName ="data//in.txt";
```

definitely it does not work on windows because there is not \data\in.txt in my folders.
I could do it by getting some arguments and skip the hard-code, no matter. there are plenty of ways.   I added my codes to see the Dir status, you may want to try.

```
String d = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    File f = new File(d);
    File filesList[] = f.listFiles();
    for(File file : filesList) {
         System.out.println("File name: "+file.getName());
         System.out.println("File path: "+file.getAbsolutePath());
         if (file.getName().equals("data")==true)
         {
             File filesList2[] = file.listFiles();
             for(File file2 : filesList2) {
             System.out.println("File name: "+file2.getName());
             System.out.println("File path: "+file2.getAbsolutePath());
             }
             
         }
         System.out.println(" ");
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case you will need to use `ENTRYPOINT` instead of `CMD`. In short:

With `CMD` when you run the container, the instruction next to container name will become the new `CMD` used (from here the error `"\\tt\\in.txt": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown`). On the other hand, with `ENTRYPOINT` the instruction you add before the container name will be added as an additional argument.

Check [this article](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/docker-cmd-vs-entrypoint) for a longer explanation about `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT`.

Comment: no, running with Entrypoint gives me the error: fileNotFound exception" in the address. but the file exist there and program works without docker

Comment: At least now seems that your jar is executing. About the path I think @tgdavies is on the right track. Containers are Linux sistems, so when you are refering paths inside container should go with `/` separator. Try to change path in mapping and path argument: `docker run -v E:\Java\Test:/tt img /tt/in.txt`