# How to open files in a Docker container outside of container using the Remote Development extension for VSCode

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to open files in a Docker container in my local operating system outside of the container using the [Remote Development extension for VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack)
(such as using right-click 'Open in Explorer' as in the [Remote - WSL extension for VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl))

I tried to:

- Build Docker Image Without Context
- Mount filesystem Volume
  so that I could access files in my operating system from my container without copying.

To build without context I can use `docker build - < Dockerfile` (see [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#build-with--)).

I can mount files via `docker run -v <path-to-file-in-host>:<path-to-file-in-container> IMAGE_NAME` (as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41092587/passing-file-as-argument-to-docker-container), and in [docker docs here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/))

From the [devcontainer.json reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/devcontainerjson-reference) it's possible to pass build args to Docker build in your devcontainer.json but this doesn't work for the `- <` as vscode-dev-containers defaults to including build context...

The extension also also automatically runs a container after build so I'm not sure how to override this.

Any tips would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR** By default dev-containers extension (as of 22/10/2020) bind mounts files from local OS to container so can can open them on local OS.

For faster bind mounting (by skipping `Sending build context to docker daemon...` during `docker build .` step) ignore all in `.dockerignore` & specify bind mount in `.devcontainer/devcontainer.json` to mount file system to container.

```
.
├── .devcontainer/devcontainer.json
├── .dockerignore
├── .git
├── .gitignore
├── Dockerfile
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── data
├── src
└── tests
```

## `.dockerignore`

```
# Ignore everything
**
```

## `.devcontainer/devcontainer.json`

From [Changing or removing the default source code mount](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers-advanced#_changing-the-default-source-code-mount)

```json
{
    ...
    "workspaceMount": "type=bind,source=${localWorkspaceFolder},target=/workspace,consistency=delegated",
    "workspaceFolder": "/workspace"
    ...
}
```

---

## (backup-plan) `docker cp`

Can also use `docker cp` to copy files in and out of a container; if I have `csv` or `txt` files in my container's data folder that I want to view in Excel on my local OS I can run:

```sh
docker cp 12890c3a2602:/workspaces/drem/data/commercial_building_benchmarks comm_bldg_bmarks
```

Where `12890c3a2602` is my container id, `/workspaces/drem/data/commercial_building_benchmarks` is the path to my data folder within my container and `comm_bldg_bmarks` is the name of the destination folder on my local OS.  See [Copying Files To And From Docker Containers](https://www.baeldung.com/ops/docker-copying-files) for more info...