# Docker container - take file as input and write out to a different file

Tags: python, docker

I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41092636/3130747), which covers "*Passing file as argument to Docker container*", and have followed that. But I'd like to be able to write out to a different file rather than overwriting the file that was passed in.

An example docker image:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim
RUN useradd --create-home --shell /bin/bash app_user
WORKDIR /home/app_user
USER app_user
# I guess I have to assume that this image is built wherever this module is...
COPY script.py .
```

where `script.py` contains (sorry if it's a bit long for what it is):

```py
import sys 
import pathlib
import argparse


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="meh",
        formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter,
    )
    parser.add_argument(
            "-c",
            "--convert_file",
            type=str,
            help="Convert this file.",
        )

    parser.add_argument(
            "-o",
            "--output_file",
            type=str,
            help="Output converted file here.",
        )

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.convert_file:
        if not args.output_file:
            output_file = '/something.txt'
        else:
            output_file = args.output_file


        file_path = pathlib.Path(args.convert_file)
        text = pathlib.Path(file_path).read_text().upper()
        pathlib.Path(output_file).write_text(text)
    
    raise SystemExit()
```

And this can be run as:

```sh
docker run -v <abs path local system>/something.txt:/home/app_user/something.txt \
    -t app:latest \
    python -m script -c /home/app_user/something.txt -o /home/app_user/something.txt
```

where `something.txt` contains:

```
this is a test, should start lowercase and finish uppercase.
```

before running, and after running it contains:

```
THIS IS A TEST, SHOULD START LOWERCASE AND FINISH UPPERCASE.
```

So, it works to a degree, but instead of overwriting `something.txt` I'd like to be able to create `something_upper.txt` (or whatever).

So - how can I take a file as input to a docker container, and write out to a different file on the local system?

Comment: If the primary goal of the script is to read and write host files, a Docker container is a poor match: by design it wants to prevent the container process from modifying the host filesystem.  Can you run this in a non-Docker Python virtual environment instead?

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks - I would like to be able to have system dependencies captured by the container as well though, so for something with a very narrow focus docker seemed like it might be suitable? I was basically thinking of something that would act like a CLI tool, but it's a container.