# Passing folder as argument to a Docker container with the help of volumes

Tags: python, docker, docker-volume

I have a python script that takes two arguments -input and -output and they are both directory paths. I would like to know first if this is a recommended use case of docker, and I would like to know also how to run the docker container by specifying custom input and output folders with the help of docker volume.
My post is similar to this : [Passing file as argument to Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41092587/passing-file-as-argument-to-docker-container).
Still I was not able to solve the problem.

Comment: I routinely advise _not_ using Docker for programs that are not long-running and whose primary goal is reading and writing host files.  A Python virtual environment would be a better match here.

Comment: You already link to a very similar question; how is this question different?  What have you already tried and what happens when you run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its common practice to use volumes to persist data or mount some input data. See the [postgres](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) image for example.

```sh
docker run -d \
  --name some-postgres \
  -e PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata \
  -v /custom/mount:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
  postgres
```

You can see how the path to the data dir is set via env var and then a volume is mounted at this path. So the produced data will end up in the volume.

You can also see in the docs that there is a directory `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` where you can mount input scripts, that run on first DB setup.

In your case it might look something like this.

```sh
docker run  \
  -v "$PWD/input:/app/input" \
  -v "$PWD/output:/app/output"  \
  myapp --input /app/input --output /app/output
```

Or you use the same volume for both.

```sh
docker run  \
  -v "$PWD/data:/app/data" \
  myapp --input /app/data/input --output /app/data/output
```